# Send raw ZPL to Zebra printer via USB

Tags: usb, zebra-printers, zpl

Typically, when I plug in my Zebra LP 2844-Z to the USB port, the computer sees it as a printer and I can print to it from notepad like any other generic printer. However, my application has some bar code features. My application parses some input and generates an in-memory string of ZPL. How would I send this ZPL data to my USB device?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found yet an easier way to write to a Zebra printer over a COM port. I went to the Windows control panel and added a new printer. For the port, I chose COM1 (the port the printer was plugged in to). I used a "Generic / Text Only" printer driver. I disabled the print spooler (a standard option in the printer preferences) as well as all advanced printing options. Now, I can just print any string to that printer and if the string contains ZPL, the printer renders the ZPL just fine! No need for special "start sequences" or funky stuff like that. Yay for simplicity!

Answer (score 22):

I found the answer... or at least, the easiest answer (if there are multiple). When I installed the printer, I renamed it to "ICS Label Printer". Here's how to change the options to allow pass-through ZPL commands:

1. Right-click on the "ICS Label Printer" and choose "Properties".
2. On the "General" tab, click on the "Printing Preferences..." button.
3. On the "Advanced Setup" tab, click on the "Other" button.
4. Make sure there is a check in the box labeled "Enable Passthrough Mode".
5. Make sure the "Start sequence:" is "${".
6. Make sure the "End sequence:" is "}$".
7. Click on the "Close" button.
8. Click on the "OK" button.
9. Click on the "OK" button.

In my code, I just have to add "${" to the beginning of my ZPL and "}$" to the end and print it as plain text. This is with the "Windows driver for ZDesigner LP 2844-Z printer Version 2.6.42 (Build 2382)". Works like a charm!

Answer (score 16):

**Visual Studio C# solution** (found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

**Step 1.)**  Create class RawPrinterHelper...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Step 2.)** Create a form with text box and button (text box will hold the ZPL to send in this example).  In button click event add code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Allow the user to select a printer.
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                // Send a printer-specific to the printer.
                RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, textBox1.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Data sent to printer.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data not sent to printer.");
            }
        }
```

With this solution, you can tweak to meet specific requirements.  Perhaps hardcode the specific printer.  Perhaps derive the ZPL text dynamically rather than from a text box.  Whatever.  Perhaps you don't need a graphical interface, but this shows how to send the ZPL.  Your use depends on your needs.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't mentioned a language, so I'm going to give you some some hints how to do it with the straight Windows API in C.

First, open a connection to the printer with [`OpenPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162751(v=vs.85).aspx). Next, start a document with [`StartDocPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145115(v=vs.85).aspx) having the `pDatatype` field of the [`DOC_INFO_1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162471(v=vs.85).aspx) structure set to `"RAW"` - this tells the printer driver not to encode anything going to the printer, but to pass it along unchanged. Use `StartPagePrinter` to indicate the first page, `WritePrinter` to send the data to the printer, and close it with `EndPagePrinter`, `EndDocPrinter` and `ClosePrinter` when done.

Answer (score 5):

ZPL is the correct way to go. In most cases it is correct to use a driver that abstracts to GDI commands; however Zebra label printers are a special case. The best way to print to a Zebra printer is to generate ZPL directly. Note that the actual printer driver for a Zebra printer is a "plain text" printer - there is not a "driver" that could be updated or changed in the sense we think of most printers having drivers. It's just a driver in the absolute minimalist sense.

Answer (score 3):

Install an share your printer: \localhost\zebra
Send ZPL as text, try with copy first:

copy file.zpl \localhost\zebra

very simple, almost no coding.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody torturing themselves with the above in 2021, if you're in the .NET world then get hold of the [RawPrint](https://github.com/frogmorecs/RawPrint) NuGet package.

From there to print your ZPL string directly to the printer, bypassing drivers, it's:

```
 IPrinter printer = new Printer();
 printer.PrintRawStream(@"Your Printer Name", GenerateStreamFromString(yourZplString), @"docname");
```

Answer (score 1):

Found amazing simple solution - working for Chrome (Windows, not tested on Mac)

`Zebra ZP 450`

1. Go here [Zebra Generic Text](https://zebratechnologies.force.com/s/article/Print-a-zpl-file-using-the-Generic-Text-Printer?language=en_US&r=105&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-seoAssistant.SeoAssistant.getSeoData=1&other.ArticlesDetailsNew.getArticles=1&ui-knowledge-components-aura-actions.KnowledgeArticleVersionCreateDraftFromOnlineAction.createDraftFromOnlineArticle=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-richText.RichText.getParsedRichTextValue=1&ui-comm-runtime-components-aura-components-siteforce-qb.Quarterback.validateRoute=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-controller.QuestionPost.getInitData=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-controller.QuestionPost.getTopicFromUrl=1)
2. Go precisely by the manual
3. No COM1 or any other ports needed - USB is enough
4. When done (named the printer ZTEXT), does not matter if it won't print a test page
5. Turn of Spooling and enable direct printing in Printer Preferences - 1 note here 1 printer is ZP450 CPT and other ZP450 only - on the other one I do not even need to turn off spooling and it worked.
6. Go to Chrome and printing ZPL from there with Chrome Print Dialog Box by selecting the ZTEXT printer (Generic / Text) Printer (Do not choose Windows Dialog Box) - we needed this for Chrome to be working

Answer (score 0):

I spent 8 hours to do that.
It is simple...

You shoud have a code like that:

```
private const int GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;

//private const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
private const int OPEN_EXISTING = 1;
private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
private StreamWriter _fileWriter;
private FileStream _outFile;
private int _hPort;
```

Change that variable content from 3 (open file already exist) to 1 (create a new file).
It'll work at Windows 7 and XP.