# Scan BarCode and print label, write to file

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a database of Parts including Part#,Bin_Location,Description. I have a process requirement to "RECEIVE" part which involves 
1. Scan part bar code with a hand-held scanner.
2. Print label with "PartNo,Description, BIN_Location.
Has anyone encountered an off the shelf solution that would meet this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Motorola Scanner Software Developer Kit (SDK) in my current application. The Motorola Scanner Software Developer Kit for Windows defines an architectural framework providing a single programming interface across multiple programming languages (such as MS .NET, C++, Java) for all scanners communication variants (such as IBMHID, SNAPI, HIDKB, Nixdorf Mode B, etc.).

[https://portal.motorolasolutions.com](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XA-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/Developer+Kits+and+Software+Tools/Bar%20Code%20Scanners%20Developer%20and%20Software%20Kits_US-EN)

Answer (score 0):

Most barcode scanners have a keyboard emulation mode, which will allow scanning to be read directly into a field in your GUI.

> [...] the barcode scanner is recognized by the PC as a second keyboard device and when you scan a barcode, all barcode data goes into the PC just as if it were being typed in on a keyboard. Just like a standard keyboard wedge scanner, no additional software is needed. Windows will automatically recognize the scanner and treat it as if it were a second keyboard connected to your PC. [[taltech.com](http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/articles/which_barcode_scanner_interface)]

On the other hand, if you decide to code directly against the hardware, [RS232](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706254/3196753) and USB/[HID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106511/3196753) are fairly common but generally involve much more coding.

In regards to printing the barcode, if you are ok with raw printing, you can write directly to a label printer with plain text using a language such as [ZPL](http://labelary.com/viewer.html).  Since you didn't mention the language you are using, here's examples in:

- CMD https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296182/3196753
- Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/9309845/3196753
- .NET https://stackoverflow.com/a/20315926/3196753, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201219/3196753

Note that whenever sending plain text a printer, the driver may need to be explicitly configured to bypass the printer driver and use a plain text driver instead.